# How to troubleshoot an AMP Stack

Tags: mysql, apache, ssl, mamp, lamp

I am trying to establish a stable AMP stack that will support multiple localhosts in a single physical environment. In my case it is a MAMP stack because I am using a Macbook pro (Sierra). I have tried both MAMP and MAMP Pro. My problem is in correctly setting ports. I have the choice setting ports to (Apache) 80, (Nginx) 81, (Apache SSL) 443, (Nginx SSL) 7443, (MySQL) 3306. Alternatively, I can use MAMP Defaults Apache (8888/8890), Nginx (7888/7890), MySQL (8889). I can get either option to work on MAMP. I can only get the default option to work on MAMP PRO. MAMP makes setting up multiple localhosts more complex. Specifically I am having port conflicts with MySQL. I am told that using the defaults I may encounter conflicts with WordPress (also in the mix).

That is the context.

My real question is this. I am not looking for an answer to this specific problem. I am looking for suggestions to what I need to study to gain the knowledge I need to troubleshoot this problem myself. I'm not totally confident I know what a port is, nor how to assess my environment to try and resolve conflicts. I want to understand the underlying issues, technologies, etc. I want to know where to begin to look, what tools to use, what the relationships are between the technologies; basically I want to know how to get "under the sheets" and look for answers myself before I have to come to the forums and get help for the really nasty problems. I love the forums, don't get me wrong. I have learned a lot from them. But, I have also burned hours and days waiting to get answers and then realizing that even though I got an answer, I don't know why it is an answer so I probably won't be able to get myself out of a similar problem later.

So, guidance please on resources for understanding the AMP stack "under the sheets" so that when things don't work "out of the box" I can at least understand the issues well enough to begin the troubleshooting process. I hope this is the right place to ask that question.

Comment: There's no code here, so this really isn't a good fit for the Stack Overflow format. In any case I'd strongly advise against using MAMP and instead encourage you to use something like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) to manage virtual machines. This creates a much more portable configuration, and with the right tooling it enables you to deploy these anywhere, even on machines with different operating systems, because you can package up the VM as-is for re-use elsewhere.

Comment: Tadman I appreciate the help. I'll look into Vagrant. It may help with the "what" and that is an advantage but I am still looking for the "why" answers. I'll keep looking.